# In Minecraft, how can I use Curse of Vanishing and Curse of Binding to my advantage in Singleplayer Hardcore Mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently traded with a villager and got a Curse of Binding and a Curse of Vanishing enchanted book. I am in version v1.14 with no mods and I want to know if I can use these books to my advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your context of Singleplayer Hardcore, neither enchant is really useful.

Curse of Binding is just annoying, as the only way you could get the armour off you if you put it on would be to wear down the durability, which is risky as you need to take damage to do this.

Curse of Vanishing, you might as well put on all your items anyway as a flex, it's hardcore, so if you die, everything gets deleted anyway. Not sure on the mechanics, but it's possible that as it's a negative enchant, it makes the 'enchantment value' of the tool/armour lower, so it's actually cheaper to repair/combine at anvil.

Answer (score 3):

The curses are meant to be negative. The best use for them, if you want to apply them intentionally, is pranks, like dispensing a pumpkin with curse of binding onto someone who isn't wearing a helmet.

Answer (score 1):

Any item or weapon enchanted with [Curse of Vanishing](https://techinfogeek.com/curse-of-vanishing/) is going to vanish or disappear after a player dies in the game.

And the cursed item is terminated forever as it is difficult to recover it.

You can use this enchantment to trick your friends by applying this Curse onto their tools, which in turn is going to vanish their tools after they die.

Gamers can also use this Curse in the PvP servers as it can help them obliterate the items when they die in a battle, which is going to ensure that their weapons cannot be used against them after they die.

Moreover, mapmakers can use this Curse to make the adventure maps harder for the players.

But it is advised to avoid this Curse entirely and make sure not to enchant anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your world is multiplayer and don't have `keepInventory`, then the Curse of Vanishing can be used on really good items you don't wan't your enemies to get their hands on, like a powerful sword/trident, or a map that leads to your secret base or something.

Obviously only use if you're not likely to get killed by mobs often *and* if you wouldn't have got back your items anyway.

Comment: The asker said that it is a singleplayer world, not multiplayer.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Yes, but Fabian's answer also allows for multiplayer